# Linux compilation error - cannot convert type ‘string’ to type ‘string&&’

Tags: c++

Linux compilation error - cannot convert type ‘string’ to type ‘string&&’, when inserting into a map containing string. The same is building fine on Windows.
My use case:

```
void insertIf(std::string str1, int value, std::map<std::string,int> &myMap) const
{
    if(value == 1)
    {
        myMap.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, int>(str1, value));       
    }
}
```

Comment: May we have a [mcve]?

Comment: Typo? `arg1.insert(std::make_pair<std::string,int>(str1,int1));` <-- `))`

Answer (score 1):

That's because `std::make_pair` takes forwarding reference as parameter. You should use `std::make_pair` with a deducing context and the constructor of `std::pair` when you want to specify template parameter explicitly.

Here's are your choices :

**make_pair:**

```
void insertIf(std::string str1, int value, std::map<std::string,int>& myMap) {
    if(value == 1 {
        myMap.insert(std::make_pair(str1, value));
    }
}
```

**pair constructor**

```
void insertIf(std::string str1, int value, std::map<std::string,int>& myMap) {
    if(value == 1 {
        myMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(str1, value));
    }
}
```

**Even better, `emplace`:**

```
void insertIf(std::string str1, int value, std::map<std::string,int>& myMap) {
    if(value == 1 {
        myMap.emplace(str1, value);
    }
}
```

---

If you really want to use `std::make_pair` with explicit parameters, you can specify the value category in the template parameter **but I advise you to not do this**, it kinda defeats the whole purpose of `std::make_pair` :

```
void insertIf(std::string str1, int value, std::map<std::string,int>& myMap) {
    if(value == 1 {
        myMap.insert(std::make_pair<std::string&, int&>(str1, value));
    }
}
```

**Edit:** it worked on Windows because you must use an outdated version of VS, which don't support forwarding reference yet.